# Kubernetes javascript API client - cloud function and Kubectl run

Tags: google-cloud-functions, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using Google Kubernetes Engine and want to fire a Pod thanks to Google Cloud Functions.

Create and deploy one when needed.

I'm looking for a way to imitate the "`kubectl run`" command.

I found Kubernetes clients but can't identify the correct method / api.

[JavaScript-Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Google Cloud Functions, I guess you can refer to the [API Client Library for Javascript](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/) and use the [Kubernetes Engine API, v1](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#containerv1) scope.
If you prefer to make requests to the master endpoint, refer to the [Kubernetes API Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#pod-v1-core)